# Глобальные переменные в функции Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я хочу, чтобы переменная "array_name", была глобальной, но никак не могу это зделать.Я пробывал с помощью global. но не получается (Можете помочь?

```html
function test(){
const splitFile = require('split-file');
splitFile.splitFile(__dirname + '/3model.h5', 10)
  .then((names) => {
    global.array_name = names;
  
    //console.log(array_name.length);

      })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error: ', err);

  })};
  console.log(array_name);
```

Comment: это не то что мне нужно!

Comment: Но это то, что есть. Придётся смириться

Comment: Это то, что вам нужно. По другому вам никак не сделать.